# Combining two columns of a table into a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my Employee table there are two columns named Empid, EmpNm

```
Empid EmpNm
001   Null
002   Ram
Null  Akhaya
Null  Tom
005   Satya
```

Two combine both the column I am using the query like

```
SELECT (Empid + EmpNm) FROM Employee
```

And the result is like

```
Null
002Ram
Null
Null
005Satya
```

But my requirement is like

```
001
002Ram
Akhaya
Tom
005Satya
```

Is there any suggestion to this query from your side ?

Answer (score 5):

try this,it will help you..

```
SELECT (ISNULL(Empid,'') +ISNULL(EmpNm,'')) AS name FROM dbo.Employee
```

Answer (score 4):

When concatenating `null` with something the result will be `null`. You can use [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to take care of that. `Coalesce` will return the first non `null` argument.

This will return a result set

```
select coalesce(Empid, '') + coalesce(EmpNm, '') as Empid
from Employee
```

This will update the Empid column in table `Employee`

```
update Employee 
set EmpID = coalesce(Empid, '') + coalesce(EmpNm, '')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it was not updating the table, I want the result on Empid column.

Comment: Do you want to update your table with the values or do you want the column name in the result set to be `Empid`?

Comment: I want the values to be reflected on Empid column so that I can delete the second column. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  IsNull(Empid, N'') + IsNull(EmpNm, N'') As FullName
FROM Employee
```